# Adding events to calendar have stopped working on ios 6

Tags: ekevent, ekeventstore

Below given is the code i am using to add event. It is working fine on ios7.
It used to worked on ios 6 as well but now it is not working

```
    EKEvent *event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:store];
            event.title = [data valueForKey:@"progname"];
            //event.startDate = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:180]; //today
            event.startDate = strDate;
            event.endDate = [event.startDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:totalSecs];  //set 1 hour meeting
            [event addAlarm:[EKAlarm alarmWithRelativeOffset:60.0f * -1.0f]];
            [event setCalendar:[store defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
            NSError *err = nil;
            [store saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent commit:YES error:&err];
```